# PHP date format Today/Yesterday

Tags: php

I was wondering if I could get some insight on how to make the display format for a time stamp say things like "Today, 12:16PM" or "Yesterday, 9:34AM". At the moment it just displays as this "11-03-2010, 12:10PM".

How would I go about making it say "Today" or "Yesterday"

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you mean "Yesterday".

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003476/human-readable-date-using-php

Answer (score 1):

Besides the duplicate answers... this blog post may also suit what you need: http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/04/php-date-in-human-readable-form-facebook-style.html